# Chamando outro terminal com python

Tags: python, bash

Estou fazendo um projeto aqui e preciso abrir outra janela do terminal, que execute o comando `ls`.

Já tentei com `subprocess` mas deu erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 8, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Meu terminal é o `bash`.

Como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar as funções disponibilizadas pelo módulo [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) para executar comandos no terminal.

```
import subprocess

cmd = ['gnome-terminal'] # Se estiver usando o GNOME
cmd.extend(['-x', 'bash', '-c', 'ls -l; exec $SHELL' ])

subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

O comando acima vai executar o `gnome-terminal` passando os argumentos necessários para que se possa executar um comando, nesse caso, `ls -l` no terminal chamado.

Para chamar o [`xterm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm) basta mudar o conteúdo da variável, deixando assim:

```
cmd = ['xterm']
cmd.extend(['-e', 'bash', '-c', 'ls -l; exec $SHELL' ])

subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Os comandos acima são aplicáveis ao [**Bash**](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash) para outros interpretadores a sintaxe pode mudar.

Comment: @QMechanic73 obitive resultado com esse comando: os.system("xterm -e 'sudo apt-get update'")

Comment: Porém com o comando a cima o programa espera a execução no xterm acaba para continua a execução do programa, teria uma forma de proseguir com o programa sem que a execução do comando no xterm tenha acabado?

Comment: @PedroSouza Utilize o `subprocess.Popen` ele faz isso. :)

Comment: Agora deu certo , obrigado!